# AWS - I changed my RDS security group's inbound rule to certain ip, and I got 502 respond when vising the main website

Tags: reactjs, express, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I'm new to hosting on AWS. Any help would be appreciated.

In short, the website was accessible when I give "0.0.0.0/0" and "::/0" access to the instance that is hosting my website while giving "0.0.0.0/0" and "::/0" access to the RDS instance.
Without changing anything to the EC2 hosting instance's security rules, I only changed my RDS instances' security group's inbound rule to only giving access to the IP of the hosting instance and my home IP.
After this, when I try to visit my website, it gives the respond of 502. I don't get it. Why did it affect the public access to my website?

My client app is built based on react, and the server is express. Only when a button is clicked on the page that is not my home page, the API is called to reach for the database.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you allow the public IP of your EC2 instance, or the private IP? If your EC2 and RDS instances are in the same VPC, the request from the EC2 instance will come from the private IP. Also, do you have any logging info on your EC2 instance that can help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Like jscott mentioned, the web app is probably connecting to your DB over another IP address than the one you whitelisted (private vs public address of the EC2). From your post I guess that your DB is also running on a public IP address since you can connect to it directly from your home address. This means that you also have to whitelist the public ip address of your EC2, since it will route over the internet.

Since you mentioned you are new to AWS, I'd also like to give some general guidance on how to design your web app on AWS, especially since I see this go wrong a lot with my customers as well:

If you're starting from scratch, try not to start with EC2 instances for your back-end. Try to go serverless (api gateway / lambda) where possible. This will save you a lot of time and money and network complexity.

If you really want to go the 'classical' route and deploy a three tier web app, I suggest you start with this tutorial: https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/reliability/100_labs/100_deploy_cloudformation/

It gives you a nice introduction to three tier VPC's and cloudformation for more reliable and secure deployments.